# Cannot read property 'arrayUnion' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add an element to an existing array in Firebase.  I am using react.  I have looked at other mentions of this issue on here and the solution is always exactly what I am already doing so help would be much appreciated. This only needs to update if the user selects a team to join and I've checked that teams is truthy

My firebase setup:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/functions'
import 'firebase/firestore'
import 'firebase/auth'
import 'firebase/storage'

// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGE_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_MEASUREMENT_ID
};

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

const db = firebaseApp.firestore()
const auth = firebaseApp.auth()
const storage = firebaseApp.storage()
// const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()

export { db, storage, auth }
```

my function:

```
import { db, storage } from '../../firebase'
...
...
...

if(teams) {
      db.collection('teams').doc(team.id).update({
        teamMembers: db.FieldValue.arrayUnion(currentUser.id)
      })
    }
```

The Error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'arrayUnion' of undefined
    at userInfoFirebase (SecondStep.js:179)
    at submitFinalData (SecondStep.js:200)
    at handleSubmit (SecondStep.js:281)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4070)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:8243)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:8275)
    at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:8288)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:8299)
    at react-dom.development.js:8508
    at batchedEventUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:22396)
    at batchedEventUpdates (react-dom.development.js:3745)
    at dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem (react-dom.development.js:8507)
    at attemptToDispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:6005)
    at dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:5924)
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:646)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11276)
    at discreteUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:22413)
    at discreteUpdates (react-dom.development.js:3756)
    at dispatchDiscreteEvent (react-dom.development.js:5889)
```

Comment: I've never used Firebase wih React, but I think you should use `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(currentUser.id)` instead of `db.FieldValue.arrayUnion(currentUser.id)` ?

Comment: ```db = firebase.firestore()``` that's how I set it up in the firebase file.

Comment: That is incorrect Bryant. Your `db` = `firebase.firestore()`, but `FieldValue` is defined on `firebase.firestore` (without `()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `db = firebase.firestore()`, but `FieldValue` is defined on `firebase.firestore` (without `()`).

You'll also need to export the `firebase` namespace with:

```
export { firebase, db, storage, auth }
```

Import it with:

```
import { firebase, db, storage } from '../../firebase'
```

And then use it with:

```
teamMembers: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(currentUser.id)
```

---

Alternatively, you can export `arrayUnion` or `FieldValue` itself, and use those.

Comment: Thank you!  I wish that was more clear in the docs.  Up until now anytime I've run into that structure I can shorten like how I tried here.  Your solution worked!

Comment: Thanks. I got this issue and wasted so much time with other answers and finally it worked after removing those braces. Been trying google search result solutions and this answer did not come up as a result, found it on another website.

Answer (score 1):

Import `arrayUnion` from fire store:

```
import { arrayUnion} from "firebase/firestore";
```

and then use this:

```
lessons: arrayUnion("greater_virginia2")
```

Comment: This is the working answer as of firebase 9.15.0. Note that the updated function no longer allows nested arrays.