# unable to append objects in firebase document

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
 var single_Catagory = [
        {
          name: title,
          price: price,
          scrachedPrice: scrachedPrice,
          color: colors,
          sizeList: sizes,
          stockStatusAvailablity: inStockAvailablity,
          productInStock: productInStock,
          rating: rating,
          productDescription: productDescription,
        },
      ];

      db.collection("catagory")
        .doc("catagories")
        .set({ electronics: single_Catagory })
        .then(() => {
          console.log("Document successfully written!");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
        });
```

this is my code for writing in my firebase firesore collection "catagroy" and it has one document "catagories",when I inserted one object I can't append other objects in firestore document. please I got stuck ..help me

Answer (score 1):

**How to add documents to firestore collection? And how to modify them?**

```
// Add a new document in collection "cities"
db.collection("cities").doc("LA").set({
    name: "Los Angeles",
    state: "CA",
    country: "USA"
})
.then(() => {
    console.log("Document successfully written!");
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
});
```

And if this document is not existing one its going to be created, but if its already there the data will be overwriten by the latest document.
Of course there is a option that can prevent that from happening.

```
var cityRef = db.collection('cities').doc('BJ');

var setWithMerge = cityRef.set({
    capital: true
}, { merge: true });
```

This explanation is very basic but usefull for further understanding of how firebase  is working. All of it is from the firebase docs, they are very well made take a look at them.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#web-version-8

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Dobromir's answer on how to add another field to the document, here's how you can add another item to the `electronics` array in your existing document:

```
var second_Catagory = {
  name: "second name",
  price: price,
  scrachedPrice: scrachedPrice,
  color: colors,
  sizeList: sizes,
  stockStatusAvailablity: inStockAvailablity,
  productInStock: productInStock,
  rating: rating,
  productDescription: productDescription,
},

db.collection("catagory")
  .doc("catagories")
  .update({ electronics: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(second_Catagory) })
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [adding items to an array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#web-version-8_11).

Comment: hi Frank thanks for the response but when i try it in my code by replacing firebase.firestore with "db" it gives me this result  Error getting document: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'arrayUnion')

Comment: Did you [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=TypeError%3A+Cannot+read+properties+of+undefined+(reading+%27arrayUnion%27)) for that error message? I'm pretty sure this has been covered before, including this explanation of why [you can't get this static member on your `db` instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66834646/cannot-read-property-arrayunion-of-undefined).